# A phrase that means: "increased" my inquisitive nature"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I would like to describe how an experience increased my natural inquisitiveness, or made me more inquisitive than I already was. For example:

> The experience opened my eyes to countless opportunities, and **increased my inquisitive nature.**

How do I phrase that sentence? I know there's some expression to do with the "spark of inquisitiveness" inside me, and "flames", but I just can't remember it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase you're looking for could be the idiomatic metaphor **[fan the flames](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fan+the+flames)**:

> to make something more intense

You could therefore say:

> The experience opened my eyes to countless opportunities, and fanned the flames of my inquisitive nature"

As you've also mentioned "spark", you could extend this metaphor by including it too; perhaps:

> The experience opened my eyes to countless opportunities, and fanned my spark of interest into the flames of inquisitiveness"

This latter phrase is less idiomatic, and more flowery than just using "fan(ned) the flames".

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic phrase ***piqued my curiosity*** comes close to mean *increased my inquisitive nature*.

> The experience opened my eyes to countless opportunities and ***piqued my curiosity***.

TFD(idioms):

> **[pique someone's curiosity](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pique+curiosity)** (and **pique someone's interest**)
>   to arouse interest; to arouse curiosity.
>
> The advertisement piqued my curiosity about the product.
>   The
>   professor tried to pique the students' interest in French literature.